# By default, an activerecord model has attr_accessor for all the table columns correct?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

By default, an activerecord model has attr_accessor for all the table columns correct?

Answer (score 11):

No, this is not correct. An active record object will have getter and setter methods for all columns, but these are not defined using `attr_accessor` nor do they act like ones that are defined using `attr_accessor`:

While the getters and setters defined by `attr_accessor` get and set instance variables, the getters and setters on an active record objects get and set values in the `@attributes` hash, which every active record object has.